# Javascript to change ElementById value from another iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Just wondering if it's possible to change a label or element in a iframe from another iframe that are both loaded on the same page?

I have 2 iframes on a page:

```
<iframe id="leftMenu" src="menu.htm" STYLE="top:90px" NAME="menu" width="270px" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="page.htm" STYLE="top:90px" NAME="AccessPage" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

From page.htm (2nd iframe) I want to be able to change a value by an ID to something else on the 2nd iframe.

For Example:
menu.htm (1st iframe) has a label on that page..

```
<label id="test">test1234</label>
```

From the page.htm (2nd iframe) I want to change the value of that label.

I have tried doing the following but had no luck:

```
document.getElementById('leftMenu').contentWindow.document.getElementById('test').value = 'test successful';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.parent` like this:

```
    window.parent.document.getElementById('leftMenu').contentWindow.document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Replaced Successful!"
```

And instead of `.value` use `.innerHTML`

**See a working DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/G2un4/4/

Tested locally and working fine also.

Comment: @Aaron Working fine.. Added Demo, I have used id of label inside left menu ifram as `testLbl`, make it accordingly.

Comment: Replacing .value with .innerHTML did the job.

Comment: what if you are using a <li> tag can't seem to change the value..<li id="input1" data="url: 'input.htm', target: 'AccessPage'">test1234</li>  any ideas?